Can I retrain an AutoModelForSequenceClassification for text generation?
My goal is to finetune Mistral 7b to write short streams of consciousness (text completion, not instruction following).
I have a large database (1m rows) of short texts scraped from the internet. I manually labeled 15k rows into good (1k) and bad (the rest, 14k) examples. My plan is to train an AutoModelForSequenceClassification on these examples to label the other 985k rows.
In this way I hope to collect around ~20k good examples of streams of consciousness to finetune Mistral 7b on.
But only finetuning on the good examples does not use the information in the bad examples, which are far greater in number. Therefore I was thinking to use Mistral 7b as base model for the AutoModelForSequenceClassification (following this Medium post) and then retrain the resulting AutoModelForSequenceClassification for text completion. This entails removing the classification head and adding new/retraining LoRA components.
Do you think this at all feasible? Would this cripple the model (eg. needing to relearn grammar) or could this be an effective way to incorporate the information of the bad counterexamples into the text generation? Or at the very least provide a good initialization point for the LoRA finetuning to text generation?

I would recommend using PEFT-LORA method to prevent Catastrophic Forgetting for LLMs (to avoid crippling the model). You can use SFTtrainer or the CustomTrainer from the medium post for training an adapter that performs your task. And use adapter.load_adapter(checkpointpath) for your PeftModel for specific task. You can now train and switch between multiple adapters too for inference so you can train it for multiple domain specific tasks.

Train a model using AutoModelForSequenceClassification + Lora. Select a model that does well.

You can re-load adapter from the saved checkpoint. set is_trainable=True and perform the retraining for text-completion task using AutoModelForSequenceClassification for text completion.


What you have is Class imbalance in your dataset.~20k good and bad data should be enough to perform fine-tunin IMO. But I have too little context on you task so I cannot be confident on the data-size.
Using Peft adapters will help you switch between the base model and your peft adapters using something like s-LORA so you can use the base model for other forms of text completions using the base Mistral Model and switch to Peft model for your domain specific task.
Hope that helps. If you can share more details I am open to help further.

Thank you for your answer. It's a bit unclear to me though. Which modules exactly are (re)trained in step 2? Are they trained from scratch or are they initialized from the learned values from step 1?

From Step 1.
Your use case itself is not clear to me. But since you mention a retraining stage in your question I am suggesting that first use PEFT method to train for your Step 1. Benchmark/Test it. Select a suitable experiment from Step 1. Then Re-train the same peft model as Step 2. This way you can have 2 versions of Fine Tuned model.
For your experiments test with different target_modules apart from q_proj, k_proj, v_proj perhaps embeddings too in different stages. It really depends on your use case.
